# When Changing from landscape to portrait or viceversa, automatically values are send to server

Tags: java, android

In below code  when changing landscape to portrait or viceversa "OUT Attendence Marked" is shown as toast and null values are inserted to database. Why changing screen to landscape or portrait is inserting values to database.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class Attendence extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button tv,tv1;
    String response;
    double originLat=9.9967683,originLon=76.2875376;
    Button btnShowLocation;
    private Context context = this;
    private TextView taska,taskb,usernametitle;
    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;
    private static final int CODE_GPS = 10;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendence);



        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, CODE_GPS);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, CODE_GPS);
            }
        } else {

        }






    tv= (Button) findViewById(R.id.in);
        tv1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.out);
        usernametitle= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernametitle);
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
/*
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
*/
        final String userid=pref.getString("userid", null);
        final String usernamedisplay=pref.getString("username",null);
        usernametitle.setText(usernamedisplay);
        Log.e("userid","userid"+userid);




        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("user_id", userid);
        AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post("attendance.php", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject responseBody) {
                response=responseBody.toString();
                Log.e("login","login"+response);
                if(responseBody.optString("message").equals("TRUE")) {
                    String task1= responseBody.optString("task1");
                    String task2= responseBody.optString("task2");
                    taska = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taska);
                    taska.setText(task1);
                    taskb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taskb);
                    taskb.setText(task2);
/*
                    Log.e("task1","task2"+task1+task2);
*/
                    Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"OUT Attendence Marked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"Cannot Be Marked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Incall();//incall
       }

            private void Incall() {
                gps = new GPSTracker(Attendence.this);
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    if(latitude==0.0||longitude==0.0){
                        Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"Try Marking Again After Turning GPS ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    float[] results = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, originLat, originLon, results);
                    Log.e("lat"+latitude,"long"+longitude);

                    float distanceInMeters = results[0]; //radius
                    boolean isWithinRange = distanceInMeters < 60;

                    if (isWithinRange) {
                        //write your code what ever you wanna perform
                        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                        params.put("user_id", userid);
                        params.put("status", "1");
                        AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
                        client.post("attendance.php", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject responseBody) {
                                response=responseBody.toString();
                                Log.e("login","login"+response);
                                if(responseBody.optString("message").equals("TRUE")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"Attendence Marked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  /*  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Attendence.this).create();
                                    alertDialog.setTitle("Attendence");
                                    alertDialog.setMessage("Attendence Marked");
                                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            });
                                    alertDialog.show();*/
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"Cannot Be Marked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody, Throwable error) {
                                Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
/*
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
*/

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not in DenInfotech. Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // \n is for new line

                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }



            }
        });
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(Attendence.this);

                // check if GPS enabled
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    float[] results = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, originLat, originLon, results);
                    float distanceInMeters = results[0];
                    boolean isWithinRange = distanceInMeters < 60;

                    if (isWithinRange) {
                       /* final Dialog openDialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                        openDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                        openDialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog Box");
                        TextView dialogTextContent = (TextView)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                        ImageView dialogImage = (ImageView)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                        Button dialogCloseButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
                        dialogCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                openDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        openDialog.show();*/

                        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder.setView(dialogLayout);

                        TextView indtruction = (TextView)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_instruction);

                        final EditText work1 = (EditText)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.task1);
                        final EditText work2 = (EditText)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.task2);
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                String workjob = work1.getText().toString();
                                String workjob1 = work2.getText().toString();
                                Log.e("userInputContent"+workjob,"userInputContent"+workjob);
                                if(workjob.equals("")){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "You must enter a name in the field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return;
                                }

                                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                                params.put("user_id", userid);
                                params.put("status", 1);
                                params.put("work1",workjob);
                                params.put("work2",workjob1);
                                Log.e("workjob","As"+workjob+workjob1);
                                AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
                                client.post("time_out.php", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject responseBody) {
                                        response=responseBody.toString();
                                        Log.e("login","login"+response);
                                        if(responseBody.optString("message").equals("TRUE")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"OUT Attendence Marked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"Cannot Be Marked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody, Throwable error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(Attendence.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                });


                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog customAlertDialog = builder.create();
                        customAlertDialog.show();

                        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                        lp.copyFrom(customAlertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                        lp.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                        lp.height = 700;
                        customAlertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);


                        //write your code what ever you wanna perform
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success Complete. Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // \n is for new line
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CODE_GPS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity recreated when you change orientation. As i can see you have written code for sending data to server inside OnCreate, it will every time when you will change orientation.

Simple Workaround for this is to stop Activity Reloadig every time you changes orientation.

this can be done by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity Tag in manifest.xml file

```
<activity
    android:name=".Attendence"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="" />
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

V-Coder is correct, but also it seems you have declared your Incall() method inside onCreate(), which will result in compilation error.